# AppEngine nodejs, random: The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I just deployed the helloworld app on Google App Engine Flexible Environment.

Randomly, let's say, one each 3-4 requests, I get this:

[image: error message]

The only change I've made from the original helloworld code provided in google cloud docs was that I changed the automatic scaling to manual and set it to 1 instance.

Anyways, I deployed the same docker image in Container Engine, and it works perfect.

There is nothing on the app logs, the request does not reach the app.

Something is not working with GAE Flexible Env. load balancer, any ideas?

Comment: Show us some code

Comment: its 100% the google nodejs hello world app: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/hello-world

as I said, the http request is not reaching the app.

Answer (score 1):

I destroyed all the instances and deleted the service.  After 24hs tried to create it again and **now it is working good**.