# Google app engine error the server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am using Google app engine and previously everything was working fine but now when I am trying to deploy my app then i am facing this error.

[image]

Then i tried to see in my logs and in logs i found the error logs were

`[error] 32#32: *2211 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 130.211.0.251, server: , request: "GET /_ah/health HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.1:8080/_ah/health", host: "10.142.0.4"`

Why am I getting this error? Previously everything was working fine and I haven't changed anything in my code.

I have also seen this SO post [/appengine-nodejs-random-the-server-encountered-a-temporary-error-and-could-not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837145/appengine-nodejs-random-the-server-encountered-a-temporary-error-and-could-not) but i cannot delete all versions of my app engine and try again.

Comment: Before downvoting my post, can you please tell me why you are downvoting this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why but problem was occuring because i was running my nodejs app on Port 3000, but as i changed it to 8080 now it is working fine. I think default port google cloud uses is 8080 maybe.